# Persistent objects in recursive python functions

Tags: python, recursion, persistent

I am trying to write a recursive function that needs to store and modify an object (say a set) as it recurses. Should I use a global name inside the function? Another option is  to modify or inherit the class of the parameter of the function so that it can keep this persistent object but I don't find it elegant. I could also use a stack if I would forgo the recursion altogether...

Is there a pythonic way of doing this? Could a generator do the trick?

Comment: It depends on the task. It sounds like a generator would work, but I have no idea what you're doing, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass through your persistent object through the recursive method.

```
def recursivemethod(obj_to_act_on, persistent_obj=None):

    if persistent_obj == None:
        persistent_obj = set()

    # Act on your object

    return recursivemethod(newobj, persistent_obj)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Normally I wouldn't complain, but in Python it's kind of important.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen this pattern before posting the question but I guess some nails need more pushing! [It was my code that didn't work not the pattern]

Comment: Also there's no method called `Set`, it's `set`.

Comment: Shouldn't `if persistent_obj == None` be `if persisten_obj is None`?

Answer (score 4):

Objects are passed by reference.  If you're only modifying an object, you can do that from within a recursive function and the change will be globally visible.

If you need to assign a variable inside a recursive function and see it after the function returns, then you can't just assign a local variable with `=`.  What you can do is update a field of another object.

```
class Accumulator: pass

def foo():
    # Create accumulator
    acc = Accumulator()
    acc.value = 0

    # Define and call a recursive function that modifies accumulator
    def bar(n):
        if (n > 0): bar(n-1)
        acc.value = acc.value + 1
    bar(5)

    # Get accumulator
    return acc.value
```

Comment: This is like a global variable isn't it? foo just simply declares and initializes acc for bar.

Comment: @kavic It's a local variable.  The variable doesn't sit in the global namespace, and there is one instance per call to foo (not one global instance).  foo doesn't just initialize acc, it also retrieves the final value from acc.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the set into the recursive method as an argument, then modify it there before passing it to the next step. Complex objects are passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a container (not an immutable data type), you can pass the object through:

```
import random

def foo(bar=None, i=10):
    if bar is None:
        bar = set()
    if i == 0:
        return bar
    bar |= set(random.randint(1, 1000) for i in xrange(10))
    return foo(bar, i - 1)

random_numbers_set = foo()
```

(Don't ask me what that's meant to do... I was just typing random things :P)

Answer (score 0):

If the object you pass is mutable then changes to it in deeper recursions will be seen in earlier recursions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a variable global to the function.
2. Pass the object around as an accumulator:

   ```
   def recurse(foo, acc=None):
       acc = {}
       recurse(acc)
   ```