# My recursive function (populates a tree structure) is adding to the root node during every loop/call

Tags: python, recursion, mutable

I have an algorithm to populate a tree like structure (class: Scan_instance_tree), but unfortunately, during each call, it is incorrectly adding to the root node's children, as well as to the new child nodes created further down in the tree.

As a clue, I saw another thread...

[Persistent objects in recursive python functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331006/persistent-objects-in-recursive-python-functions)

...where this problem was mentioned briefly, and it was suggested that the parameters passed had to be mutable. Is that the answer, and how would I do this, in this example???

Here is my current code:

```
class Field_node(object):
    field_phenotype_id = -1
    field_name = ''
    field_parent_id = -1
    child_nodes = []          


class Scan_instance_tree(object):
    root_node = None  

    def __init__(self, a_db):
        self.root_node = Field_node()
        scan_field_values = self.create_scan_field_values(a_db)   # This just creates a temporary user-friendly version of a database table    
        self.build_tree(scan_field_values)  

    def build_tree(self, a_scan_field_values):
        self.root_node.field_name = 'ROOT'      
        self.add_child_nodes(a_scan_field_values, self.root_node)


    def add_child_nodes(self, a_scan_field_values, a_parent_node):
        i = 0
        while i < len(a_scan_field_values):
            if a_scan_field_values[i]['field_parent_dependancy'] == a_parent_node.field_phenotype_id:
                #highest_level_children.append(a_scan_field_values.pop(a_scan_field_values.index(scan_field))) 
                child_node = Field_node()
                child_node.field_phenotype_id = a_scan_field_values[i]['field_phenotype_id']
                child_node.field_name = a_scan_field_values[i]['field_name']
                child_node.field_parent_dependancy = a_scan_field_values[i]['field_parent_dependancy']

                a_parent_node.child_nodes.append(child_node)
                a_scan_field_values.remove(a_scan_field_values[i])

                # RECURSION: get the child nodes
                self.add_child_nodes(a_scan_field_values, child_node)
            else: 
                i = i+1
```

If I remove the recursive call to self.add_child_nodes(...), the root's children are added correctly, ie they only consist of those nodes where the field_parent_dependancy = -1
If I allow the recursive call, the root's children contain all the nodes, regardless of the field_parent_dependancy value.

Best regards

Ann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your `Field_node` class, the line

```
    child_nodes = []
```

is actually instantiating a single list as a class attribute, rather than an instance attribute, that will be shared by all instances of the class.

What you should do instead is create instance attributes in `__init__`, e.g.:

```
class Field_node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.field_phenotype_id = -1
        self.field_name = ''
        self.field_parent_id = -1
        self.child_nodes = []
```