# How to use a dictionary in recursion

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, copy

I have a recursive function that is similar to DFS on a graph G=(V,E) that finds all simple paths. The recursion is in a for loop so that when the function returns it may recurse again before returning itself.

Just to set the picture:

```
def algo(M,v):
    for u in v.neighbors:
        # do stuff
        M[u.name] = u     # dictionary
        algo(M,u)
```

However since M is a dictionary, it is treated as a mutable object so that when the function returns it does not restore M like it would for immutable objects. What is the best pythonic way of accomplishing this?

I don't think the deepcopy function in the copy library will be the best choice due to the problems outlined in the docs causing a recursive loop: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

How can this be done?

Comment: why are you doing `M[u.name] = u`?

Comment: say like u and v are instances of a node class and M is a dictionary that remembers which node we have traversed in the 'working' branch and then there will be some operation to possibly add M to a overall data structure if it leads to the end destination and then M needs to be restored when we return

Comment: okay I understand, so what exactly is the problem? or are you just trying to find a better way to restore the dictionary?

Comment: I want to do the opposite of this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331006/persistent-objects-in-recursive-python-functions

Comment: deepcopy doesnt seem a good solution in recursion so I want  a better way

Comment: It seems like deepcopy is your best bet if all you want is an original copy of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want to insert an item into a dictionary, recur, and then remove the item:

```
def algo(M, v):
    for u in v.neighbors:
        # do stuff
        M[u.name] = u  # temporarily extend dictionary
        result = algo(M, u)
        del M[u.name]  # clean up
        # check result
```

If you want to make sure the dictionary is pristine for the next iteration and recurance, you can pass an augmented (shallow) copy:

```
def algo(M, v):
    for u in v.neighbors:
        # do stuff
        # create a new extended dictionary on the fly
        result = algo({**M, u.name: u}, u))
        # no need to clean up afterwards
        # check result
```

If you're not running Python 3.5 or later, then use a more verbose syntax, something like:

```
def algo(M, v):
    for u in v.neighbors:
        # do stuff
        # create a new extended dictionary on the fly
        result = algo(dict(list(M.items()) + [(u.name, u)]), u))
        # no need to clean up afterwards
        # check result
```

Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that your second result is more desired, where this may get tricky is if I am passing nodes in a data structure and traversing. I think the copy makes the most sense.